# How does Shape Climate work?

Tags: powers, dawn-of-worlds

In Dawn of Worlds how does the Shape Climate power work?  Is it allowed to effectively Shape Land over geologic time (like the first age)?  What makes it different than shape land and what should it not be allowed to do that Shape Land should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things that Shape Land does that Shape Climate cannot (such as for example creating mountains, hills or seas) and a number of things that Shape Climate does that Shape Land cannot (such as lowering or increasing temperature, adding fog, violent storms, or other weather features)

However, there is indeed an overlap. The example itself mentions "turning a forest into a jungle". When it comes up, simply use the cheaper option. It'll give everyone more points to do other cool stuff with.

Personally I would say that as long as you keep the terrain's basic state the same (so the elevation, density of vegetation, level of water, etc) then it's probably okay to do with Shape Climate. As soon as you change the terrain's basic state, it should probably be Shape Land. For example, turning an undrawn piece of terrain into a flatland-swamp with limited vegetation by using "Shape Climate: loads of rain" is probably okay, but doing the same and trying to end with a heavily overgrown swamp is not, as that would require you to add vegetation. (Ie: "Shape Land: Forest")

But then, using Shape Land to immediately create an overgrown swamp would be okay. Shape Land is the more expensive spell and it should be able to do such things. (It's even mentioned in the examples that you can directly make both Forests and Jungles, even though Shape Climate *can* convert one back into the other later.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's reread the power descriptions (emphasis mine).

> **Shape Land** – This power directs the creation, modification, or erosion of mountains, hills, lakes, streams, rivers, forests, jungles, deserts, grasslands, tundra, steppes, and other land forms. **On the game map**, this power allows the creation of land forms within a 1 inch diameter area. Roughly. Using this power repeatedly can create whole ranges of mountains, inland seas, or vast wastelands. Use your imagination, and don't forget a few waterfalls. You don't need to take up the whole area if you have a fun idea.
>
> **Shape Climate** – This power directs weather patterns that are frequent in a rough 1" area, like fog, rain, snow, sun, heat, cold, sleet. You may wish to create snowy steppes, or hot jungle upon your forests.

Of these two powers, only one does directly affect the game map. While *Shape Land* is a dramatic and often catastrophical change of the landscape, *Shape Climate* is a much more subtle change, sometimes offering more narrative possibilities, e.g. when the land in question is inhabited.

Please note that even in the first age each round of play is approximately 500 years, so we can't really talk about geologic time. The climate is simply not enough to significantly change the land; maybe the torrential downpours will lower the average temperature of the desert over a couple millenia, but they hardly be enough to create a grassland or a forest.

On the other hand, if the players unanimously agree that certain weather should change the land in a certain way, go for it! The game is a narrative for fun; whichever creates most interesting and fun story goes.